# Earliest sci-fi film or program where an actor plays themself

Tags: movie, tv, history-of, actors

The trailer for the [The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special](https://youtu.be/OYhFFQl4fLs) features Kevin Bacon, appearing to play himself.

What is the earliest sci-fi film or television program where an actor has played themselves?

I know that the non sci-fi program [Extras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extras_(TV_series)) relied on this as a major plot element, but I'm interested in what sci-fi film or program has done this.

- I will accept an individual playing themselves straight or as a version that is worse or better than their real world self.
- The actor does not need to be a main member of the productions cast, and can appear in a single episode of a program or a single scene in a film.
- Films such as [Galaxy Quest](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0177789/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk) do not count as while the actors are playing characters who are in a program. Tim Allen, Sigourney Weaver, Alan Rickman, Tony Shalhoub, Sam Rockwell, and Daryl Mitchell are not playing themselves but actors in a TV program.

Comment: How small a role does this need to be?  What about cameos?

Comment: What about a role like Kareem Abdul-Jaffar in Airplane, where he was playing a character (Roger Murdock) but another character identified him as the actor? Or Julia Roberts in Ocean's Twelve, where she played a character that was a dead ringer for the actual Julia Roberts?

Comment: I was thinking about Hawking's cameo on TNG, but the new answer has that beat by 70 years...

Comment: It took a bit of sifting to find, but I bet someone beats it with a French, Italian or possibly Russian Entry - or radio if anyone can find that set of references. @DavidW

Comment: Does this count, a radio play from 1908 featuring L Frank Baum: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000679/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm

Comment: @DavidW - the Hawking thing is too squishy. He's not playing himself, but a hologram of Hawking. That kind of squishiness is my reason for dv :shrug:

Comment: Ed Wood had a cameo as "Man reading newspaper " in _Plan 9 from Outer Space_ (1957).

Comment: You may need to define what you consider an actor.

Comment: @DavidW: I believe Stephen Hawking remains the only person to have played themselves on _Star Trek_ though.

Comment: By 1950, the practice must have been well established. I say that because *Harvey*, in an obvious spoof of it, has the credits list "Harvey as Himself."

Comment: I get what you are after though I have no examples.  But basically stuff like Donald Trump in Home Alone 2 to William Shatner in Free Enterprise for anyone who doesn't get it.

Comment: I'd argue that any role played by Jimmy Durante was really Jimmy Durante playing *Jimmy Durante as <whatever>*. But that's probably not technically a correct answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1935: the movie serial [The Phantom Empire](https://scifist.net/2019/07/29/the-phantom-empire/). A vehicle for the singing cowboy [Gene Autry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Autry), who plays a singing cowboy named Gene Autry, so presumably a fictional version of himself (and there is a story-within-a-story, a radio show that Gene Autry has to broadcast in which he plays a character also named Gene Autry). The science fiction element comes in when Autry discovers a technologically advanced underground civilization named Murania, said in the story to be the basis for the real-life legends of [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28mythical_lost_continent%29). The Muranians also make use of what appear to be robots wearing cowboy hats:

[image]

Comment: Ooh, nice.  How did you find that?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: @DavidW I was looking to see if anyone played themselves in 50s sci-fi so I googled *"played himself" 1950s science fiction* and [this article](https://scifist.net/2019/07/29/the-phantom-empire/) showed up in the first page of results for me even though "1950s" doesn't appear in the article. I had actually heard of this serial before but not seen it, and it didn't occur to me when I was thinking about possibilities.

Comment: BTW, more searching with similar terms also turned up the movie [*Life Returns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_Returns) which according to [this](https://catalog.afi.com/Film/5223-LIFE-RETURNS?sid=056d7187-96bd-4949-b279-9b7b2b31f0ee&sr=9.715214&cp=1&pos=0) had a preview screening in 1934 or '35. It was a fictionalized story about reviving the dead based on experiments on dogs done by a real scientist, Robert E Cornish, who appeared in the film, but the articles just say it incorporated footage of him doing experiments, so he may not have been "acting" in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 16):

1925: [The Lost World](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0016039/). (IMDB tags as Sci-Fi).

[image: Dinosaur poster from outside a theatre of old]

Wikimedia commons, public domain, source [Wikipedia 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_World_(1925_film)#Cast).

Naturally featuring ever-popular dinosaurs, this film based on the book of the same name by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle featured [a cameo by the author *as himself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_World_(1925_film)#Cast) right at the top of the film (missing from some prints).

Original reference from Archive.org: [Lederer, Josie P. (June 1925). "The Lost World". Pictures and Picturegoer. Vol. 9, no. 52. pp. 12–13.](https://archive.org/details/picture10odha/page/n243/mode/2up?view=theater).

Comment: The question specifically asks about **actors** who played themselves. I don't believe Arthur Conan Doyle was an actor.

Comment: @user14111 imdb has an entry for him as an actor.

Comment: @Moriarty IMDb has an [entry for Air Force General Michael E. Ryan](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1575396/) based purely on his one cameo (as himself) in an episode of *Stargate SG-1*.  An entry in IMDb does not make one an actor.

Comment: @DavidW It occurred to me just after posting, this isn't entirely satisfactory basing his credentials as an actor on the single film entry here - I did search for evidence of other appearances, but none found.

Comment: Arthur Conan Doyle had a segment at the beginning where he talked about the story, but he wasn't part of the fictional world of the movie, didn't interact with any of the characters etc., so I don't think this would necessarily count as playing himself.

Comment: Great film, but I agree with the points that ACD was neither an actor, nor did he appear in the film itself (just an introductory segment.)

Comment: Agreed that this doesn't count. It's more like Rod Serling and Alfred Hitchcock doing the intros in their TV shows.

Comment: I suppose to fit the apparent intent of the question, for an actor to 'play themselves' in a film, they would have to have been an actor *prior* to the film in which they appear as themselves.

Comment: you're all nerds.

Answer (score 8):

[Don Ho](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0387290/), whose first actor credit on IMDb lists him as "Kamaki" in an episode of the series [*Hawaiian Eye*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052472/) has 2 relevant appearances.  (Note that both of these list him in the *role* of "Don Ho" under an "Actor" credit as opposed to an appearance as "Himself," "Self" appearances being listed separately.)

Don Ho appeared in "[The Bat's Kow Tow](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519505/)," a **1966** episode of [*Batman*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059968/). (Note that the appearance is uncredited, but he still is listed as appearing as "Don Ho" and not "Himself.")  Ho also appeared in the 1967 season 3 episode "[Jeannie Goes to Honolulu](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0609110/)" of [*I Dream of Jeannie*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058815/), directly credited as "Don Ho," though whether this is on-topic or not is debatable.

Even though Don Ho is primarily known as a musician, he has 18 listed actor appearances, at least 5 of which are not as "Don Ho," so I figure he counts as an actor as well.

Comment: @user14111 Oh, good point.  I found the *Batman* reference, and got distracted because it wasn't credited.

Comment: Are those really Science Fiction movies? I suppose Batman could be.

Comment: @CGCampbell It is plausible that Batman, Gilligan's Island, etc are documentaries, and this is all perfectly cromulent to any Thermians watching....